# List of changed files in RPM

Tags: linux, rpm

I wonder, if there is a way to do the following:
I have rpmA-v1 installed on the system. It has a lot of config files which user can edit for their purposes. Then, I want to install new version of rpmA, say, rpmA-v2 and before installing it I want to back up those config files, which were edited, not to edit config files one more time.

Is there any way to know which files were edited in such a situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about config files related to given package, `rpm` already has pretty robust mechanism for this known as `.rpmnew`/`.rpmsave`.

If package is being upgraded, at the discretion of package creator/maintainer there are 2 possible actions that may be taken by `rpm`:

1. Old config is preserved intact say at `/etc/myprog/config`, and new one is installed right next to it as `/etc/myprog/config.rpmnew`.  Presence of `*.rpmnew` file typically means that old config was NOT edited.
2. Old config is renamed to `/etc/myprog/config.rpmsave`, and new one is installed as`/etc/myprog/config` (replacing old one). New config may be completely fresh (vanilla) or it may incorporate settings inherited from old, `.rpmsave`'d version. Presence of `*.rpmsave` files is pretty robust sign that config files were actually edited by `rpm`.

Typically, after upgrading of one or more packages (or the whole system) it is recommended to search for all `.rpmnew`/`.rpmsave` files using command like

```
find /etc -name "*.rpmsave" -or -name "*.rpmnew"
```

and carefuly inspect all configs against their `.rpmnew`/`.rpmsave` versions (if they are around) to make sure that settings are correct. You can use `diff -u` to see text diffs or `meld` for graphical diff/merge.

Comment: Huh? That's wonderful :) I didn't even thougth that RPM will handle such a cases by itself. Will try this out. Thank you very much!

Comment: @mr.nothing But this accounts only for files marked as "config files" by the packager. If he failed to do so, you are stuck.

Comment: @glglgl, hm, never heard about that... I create my packages using maven rpm plugin and, likely, there are no such an options to mark some file as config ones. Thanks for letting me know! I'll investigate it a little bit.

Comment: @mr.nothing See http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html - here you can read about **The %config Directive**. They forgot about (noreplace), however...

Answer (score 6):

@mvp has provided a good way to determine changed config files - provided they are marked as such.

If they aren't, you can/should verify the installed package with `rpm -V packagename` in order to display any changed files.

Comment: That's a great way as well! Thanks a lot!